# Razor view throwing error when converting raw HTML

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a string a characters (address) being passed from the viewmodel to the view. I am setting the address to a variable to be used by javascript/jquery. But if I have a string like

> "Alamo Square Park, Steiner St & Hayes Street, San Francisco, CA 94117, USA"

when I set the variable in my razor view file like this

> var viewModelFormattedAddress = @Html.Raw(Model.FormattedAddress);

I get an error!

If I just pass the value in quotes as a string to the variable it converts the special characters to non HTML characters like so

> "Alamo Square Park, Steiner St &amp Hayes Street, San Francisco, CA 94117, USA"

if I do this

> var viewModelFormattedAddress = "@Model.FormattedAddress";

I don't want this because then I have to convert it back.

Why is an error being thrown when I do a @Html.Raw() call?

UPdate -

here is what I'm trying

```
var viewModelFormattedAddress = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.FormattedAddress)).ToString();
```

this is the error

> JavaScript critical error at line 297, column 41 in https://localhost:44368/Home/Events?date=7/19/2017&formattedaddress=Alamo+Square+Park,+Steiner+St+&+Hayes+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA+94117,+USA&latitude=37.7763694&longitude=-122.434819&maptype=establishment\n\nSCRIPT1002: Syntax error

and this is what it's showing in the dynamic page

```
var viewModelFormattedAddress = &quot;Alamo Square Park, Steiner St \u0026 Hayes Street, San Francisco, CA 94117, USA&quot;;
```

Comment: What error? (and it needs to be `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.FormattedAddress));` - I'm guessing that you might also have new line characters in that address?)

Comment: I'm going to post more details

Comment: Its already a `string` - you do not need `.ToString()` :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot the quotes... try this:

```
var viewModelFormattedAddress = "@Html.Raw(Model.FormattedAddress)";
```

Instead of

```
var viewModelFormattedAddress = @Html.Raw(Model.FormattedAddress);
```